# Not Able to Start windows service on windows server 2016 using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server

I am trying to start windows service using Powershell. The Command is `Start-Service -Name 'Log Reader' -Verbose`

I ran above command with evlevated powershell with Admin rights.

But I am getting following

> Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Log Reader (Log Reader)'.

At line:1 char:1

```
Start-Service -Name 'Log Reader' -Verbose

  + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

On Server it is not working but on local machine, it is working fine.

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Windows services have a Display name, and a Service name.

1. Fire up `services.msc`
2. Find your service in the list
3. Right-click and go to Properties
4. Make a note of the `Service name`
5. Update your PowerShell to use the correct name

In the image below, you can see the Windows Biometric Service would be started by calling

`Start-Service -Name 'WbioSrvc'`

**NOT** `Start-Service -Name 'Windows Biometric Service'`

[image]